# Jquery separate decimal number

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have decimal numbers like:

18.1234567

5.2345678

-77.7654321

-0.4567891

How can I separate number before and after decimal dot using Jquery and is there any function that can recognize negative value of the selected number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use javascript split function

```
var str = '4.5';
var substr = str.split('.');
// substr[0] contains "4"
// substr[1] contains "5"
```

to see if this negative you can use 
javascript also :

```
 nagative = str.indexOf("-");
```

if its return 1 (not zero) it is a negative number.

Comment: if use split function as result I get the same decimal number where the dot is replaced with comma, like 18,1234567

Comment: like in the example i wrote you get array with 2 entry , entry 0 - is before dot , and entry 1 is after the dot.

Answer (score 10):

I'm assuming your numbers are held as decimals, not as strings? In which case, just use the math functions:

```
Math.floor ( 18.1234567 ) // = 18
18.1234567 - Math.floor ( 18.1234567 ) // = .1234567
```

And checking for a negative number is just checking if it's < 0.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need jQuery for this at all:

```
var parts = num.toString().split('.');
```

If you want the values as integers instead of strings, you can just do `parseInt(parts[0])` to cast back to integer.